# Buddhist funeral process

Tags: traditions, death, rituals

I am seeking a proper guide on Buddhist funeral process in India.
What are the things needs to be taken care while performing the last Ceremony

With Metta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal Buddhist funeral but some customs have developed in Buddhist countries around Buddhism. Following may be of some help:

- [Ceremonies and Funeral Rites for the Dead](http://www.buddhanet.net/d_cermon.htm)
- [Funeral (Buddhism)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funeral_(Buddhism))
- [A Guide to a Proper Buddhist Funeral](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/buddhist_funeral.pdf)