# Online Funeral vs Actual Funeral (Buddhism)

Tags: lay-buddhism, lay-practices, rituals

This post is relevant to [Buddhist Funeral Process](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/7764/buddhist-funeral-process)

Can i do it online like playing the recorded video as below with nice TV and nice sound system ?

[Funeral Chanting - Theravada Buddhism - Pali - Abhayagiri Monastics (+ chanting text)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n16o2TYpKyQ)

Q) Effect would be same? Guess it's much better and safe especially in this Pandemic to avoid crowd and putting the monks into risk?

Answer (score 2):

Funeral rituals do not determine whether a dead person goes to heaven or hell.

Instead, their own karma determines their outcome.

The following sutta ([SN 42.6](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.006.than.html)) explains this.

> Then Asibandhakaputta the headman went to the Blessed One and on
> arrival, having bowed down to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting
> there he said to the Blessed One: "The brahmans of the Western lands,
> lord — those who carry water pots, wear garlands of water plants,
> purify with water, & worship fire — can take [the spirit of] a dead
> person, lift it out, instruct it, & send it to heaven. But the Blessed
> One, worthy & rightly self-awakened, can arrange it so that all the
> world, at the break-up of the body, after death, reappears in a good
> destination, the heavenly world."
>
> "Very well, then, headman, I will question you on this matter. Answer
> as you see fit. What do you think: There is the case where a man is
> one who takes life, steals, indulges in illicit sex; is a liar, one
> who speaks divisive speech, harsh speech, & idle chatter; is greedy,
> bears thoughts of ill-will, & holds to wrong views. Then a great crowd
> of people, gathering & congregating, would pray, praise, &
> circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the heart [saying,]
> 'May this man, at the break-up of the body, after death, reappear in a
> good destination, the heavenly world!' What do you think: would that
> man — because of the prayers, praise, & circumambulation of that great
> crowd of people — at the break-up of the body, after death, reappear
> in a good destination, the heavenly world?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "Suppose a man were to throw a large boulder into a deep lake of
> water, and a great crowd of people, gathering & congregating, would
> pray, praise, & circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the
> heart [saying,] 'Rise up, O boulder! Come floating up, O boulder! Come
> float to the shore, O boulder!' What do you think: would that boulder
> — because of the prayers, praise, & circumambulation of that great
> crowd of people — rise up, come floating up, or come float to the
> shore?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "So it is with any man who takes life, steals, indulges in illicit
> sex; is a liar, one who speaks divisive speech, harsh speech, & idle
> chatter; is greedy, bears thoughts of ill-will, & holds to wrong
> views. Even though a great crowd of people, gathering & congregating,
> would pray, praise, & circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm
> over the heart — [saying,] 'May this man, at the break-up of the body,
> after death, reappear in a good destination, the heavenly world!' —
> still, at the break-up of the body, after death, he would reappear in
> destitution, a bad destination, the lower realms, hell.
>
> "Now what do you think: There is the case where a man is one who
> refrains from taking life, from stealing, & from indulging in illicit
> sex; he refrains from lying, from speaking divisive speech, from harsh
> speech, & from idle chatter; he is not greedy, bears no thoughts of
> ill-will, & holds to right view. Then a great crowd of people,
> gathering & congregating, would pray, praise, & circumambulate with
> their hands palm-to-palm over the heart [saying,] 'May this man, at
> the break-up of the body, after death, reappear in destitution, a bad
> destination, the lower realms, hell!' What do you think: would that
> man — because of the prayers, praise, & circumambulation of that great
> crowd of people — at the break-up of the body, after death, reappear
> in destitution, a bad destination, the lower realms, hell?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "Suppose a man were to throw a jar of ghee or a jar of oil into a deep
> lake of water, where it would break. There the shards & jar-fragments
> would go down, while the ghee or oil would come up. Then a great crowd
> of people, gathering & congregating, would pray, praise, &
> circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the heart [saying,]
> 'Sink, O ghee/oil! Submerge, O ghee/oil! Go down, O ghee/oil!' What do
> you think: would that ghee/oil, because of the prayers, praise, &
> circumambulation of that great crowd of people sink, submerge, or go
> down?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> "So it is with any man who refrains from taking life, from stealing, &
> from indulging in illicit sex; refrains from lying, from speaking
> divisive speech, from harsh speech, & from idle chatter; is not
> greedy, bears no thoughts of ill-will, & holds to right view. Even
> though a great crowd of people, gathering & congregating, would pray,
> praise, & circumambulate with their hands palm-to-palm over the heart
> — [saying,] 'May this man, at the break-up of the body, after death,
> reappear in a destitution, a bad destination, the lower realms, hell!'
> — still, at the break-up of the body, after death, he would reappear
> in a good destination, the heavenly world."
>
> [SN 42.6](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.006.than.html)

Comment: so this action via online is better? 1. keep the monks safe, 2. I can look for suitable Buddhism online video that everyone can easily understand so the visitors can benefit also Dharma when is shared ? Normally those Buddhism ritual perform by monk rather difficult to be understand especially free thinker

Comment: i can request Monk friend to have online Q&A so more people gain understand about Buddhism. By that, parent doing good deed afterlife ?

Comment: @littlestar Yes. Please ask your monks for professional advice.

Comment: Thanks. Let's see what Bhante says

Answer (score 0):

The practice of the Noble Path, good householder, leads to the safety from aging, sickness and decay, while running away, hiding doesn't and refuge like into youtube and internet-realms just increases the cemeteries in this world.

As for the duty of giving a proper funeral to one's supporters: the amount of sacrifices would depend at least on ones possibilities. Some organize fests, some see it as an importand occasions to reflect on the Dhamma, some symbolic shave their heads, some remind [the goad](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.113.than_en.html) and go forth.

Looking online into the world, suffering and death, doesn't seems to increase the understanding of the first Noble truth at all in the world, but suggests that one always can switch to a better one and to feel safe behind the screen.