# Funeral and Spread of Buddhism - Break the Hell 破地狱

Tags: rituals, chinese-buddhism

Normally Chinese funeral ritual combined with Taoism and Buddhism and there is something call break the hell ritual. [Break the Hell Ritual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-BTfOtytfY)

I had noticed the ritual Sifu before recited the Original Vows of Ksitigarbha Bodhisattva Sutra so i did ask him some of the basic like first statement below and he is unable to answer means likely the ritual being non effective so i dont plan to hire any of them and it's very expensive too.

無  上  甚  深  微  妙  法 - The  unexcelled,  most  profound,  and  exquisitely
wondrous Dharma

Q) If a proper ritual being done as per link [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/46113/online-funeral-vs-actual-funeral-buddhism/46114?noredirect=1#comment74096_46114), then Dharma is being shared to 10 highly influential people then it multiples to 10k people in a few years time then a hell is possibly being broke theoretically ? I plan to request a monk to have some basic Buddhism sharing as many free thinkers and wrong livelihood/confuse of Buddhists here. But one suffering still applicable afterlife until enough merits accumulated from the funeral itself?

Well, heavy crime punishment cant be avoided I believe. Guess, this would something like a appeal and reduce no of years like in the prisons.
[Iti 100-112](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/why-there-is-limited-sharing-in-buddhism)

> "There are these two kinds of gifts: a gift of material things & a
> gift of the Dhamma. Of the two, this is supreme: a gift of the Dhamma.
>
> "There are these two kinds of sharing: sharing of material things &
> sharing of the Dhamma. Of the two, this is supreme: sharing of the
> Dhamma.

Comment: Are you looking for the theoretical basis of this ritual or just asking whether the claim about the number of people receiving merit is valid?

Comment: the claim about the number of people receiving merit is valid? The Karma and Merits system where source is from the decease

Comment: @viptrongproz98 even i  managed to break the hell then it's just prolong the time before actual punishment to one afterlife. If one doesn't change and still continue breaking precepts then even more worse karma. Even to myself. right?

Comment: There are practices in other Sinosphere countries performed to ensure those stuck in hell will reach the Pure Land (or other 'good' realms) in their next life via a mechanism of sharing merit. I'm not sure if this ritual has such purpose in mind, so I can't say anything yet.

Comment: @viptrongproz98 guess it's possible but need very high ranking and level Monk.. see my sifu willing to help or not.. just feeling me over help my dad :D .. u can continue this on the chat